# How can I make a cron to execute a php script?

Tags: php, cron

I want execute a php script each five minutes at my server, it is a php script which works fine alone, I tried since my browser and since console using "php -f php_file.php". But I need execute it automatically every days. I was searching on Google and here to make it but any solution worked for me:

First I edit my crontab and I also restart the cron to make sure that it was updated correctly.

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/myscript.php
```

and I tried the following too:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/myscript.php
```

I made the script executable too, review my system log (where I can see that my cron is executing correctly, but it doesn't execute php script) and I also try to redirect the output of cron to a file, but it leaves the file empty.
Anyone can help me?

Best regards

Comment: "where I can see that my cron is executing correctly, but it doesn't execute php script" — What output do you get? What leads you to think that cron is running but not running the PHP script? "I also try to redirect the output of cron to a file" — How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track by making your script executable.

Do it again if needed

```
$ chmod +x script.php
```

Add this to the very top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// here goes your script
```

you can test if the script executes by running it like this

```
$ ./script.php
```

set-up your `cron` job like below to set-up some logging but make sure you output something from your script, use `print` or `echo` and a relevant message.

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/script.php >> /var/www/script.log 2>&1
```

we are redirecting both standard output and errors into the `script.log` file.

check every 5 min for activity.

---

Update:

Try this in your php script

```
$file = '/var/www/script.txt';
for($i=0;$i<9;$i++){
    $entry = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . " " . $i . PHP_EOL;
    echo $entry; // this should write to the log file

    file_put_contents($file, $entry, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); 
    // and this should write to the script.txt file
}
```

basically we are giving the full path to the file and passing the `FILE_APPEND` flag so we don't overwrite every time.

Run the script and check if the file is created, the default behavior is to create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I added a print and yes it showing it but in my php script I need open and write a file. I'm testing it with the following code: <code>
<?php

$fp = fopen(“file.txt”,”a”);
for($i=0;$i<9;$i++){
 echo $i;
 fwrite($fp,$i);
}
fclose($fp);
?>

</code> But the cron job isn't creating the file, thanks for reply me

Comment: can't see the relevant code, better edit your question and include it there instead of here in the comments.

Comment: Yeah it works perfectly. Thanks you for your time, I really appreciate it. Cheers!