# How to run cron job in php

Tags: php, cron

I have php function that I wnat to run every 15 minutes. I found some questions like this:

> [How can I make a cron to execute a php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099274/how-can-i-make-a-cron-to-execute-a-php-script)

and in my case I should use this:

`*/15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /path/to/my/file.p`

But should I run this command in terminal or put it in my file? And once, it is executed, will it run all the time or will have time limit?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm new to cron jobs..Could you explain, please?

Comment: In linux distros, type `crontab -e` at the terminal to edit. There is where you put the line. `crontab -l` to view the jobs.

Comment: The `crontab -e` is the command to edit the crontab file which you shouldn't edit directly. If you have cron, it's already there.

Answer (score 6):

PHP doesn't run cron jobs, your server (or operating system) is doing this. There are two ways to put your cron job to work:

## #1

Using the shell command `crontab`. The command `crontab -l` will list all existing cronjobs for your user (most likely there are none yet). `crontab -e` will open an editor window where you can put in a you cron job as a new line. Save, and your cron job is now running. `crontab -l` again and you will see it listet. `crontab -r` to remove all the cont jobs.

You can also start a cron job from a file. Simply type `crontab filename` (eg. `crontab textfile.txt`)

Alternatively you can also start it from within PHP. Just put your cron job into a file and start it via `exec()` like so:

```
file_put_contents( 'textfile.txt', '*/15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /path/to/my/file.php' );
exec( 'crontab textfile.txt' );
```

## #2

If you have admin privileged on your system you can create a file in `/etc/cron.d/` (for example, call it `my_cronjob`) and put your cron job there. In this case you probably want to run it as a user (not as admin, that would be rather insecure). This is quite easy to do, just add the user name like so:

```
*/15 * * * * user_name /usr/local/bin/php -q /path/to/my/file.p
```

(In this case the cron job will not be listet under `crontab -l`)

---

**Answering your second question:** As long as the cron job is listet in `crontab -l` or as long as the file is sitting in `/etc/cron.d` the cron job is running, in your case, every 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I use `<?php crontab script.txt` should I put this in script.txt file? Would it execute my file script.txt? And if I use `file_put_contents( 'script.txt', '*/15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /path/to/my/file.p' );
exec( 'crontab script.txt' );` where should I put it - in header.php file or where? Thanks!

Comment: @mistery_girl Usually you start a cron job once, and then let it run, so the `header.php` is not a good place. Create a new PHP file which you will call only once, manually (meaning: type its URL directly into you address bar), to start the cron job. `file_put_contents` will create a file on the server and `exec( 'crontab file' );` will then add it as a cron job. Using `<?php crontab script.txt` will not work.

Comment: Can I use: `file_put_contents( 'script.php', '*/15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /script.php' );
exec( 'crontab script.php' );`   - to be the same file - crob job and my php code?

Comment: Sorry, the name `script.txt` was misleading. All you need is a simple text file that contains one line if text: `*/15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /script.php`. To create this textfile with php you use the function `file_put_contents( 'textfile.txt', '*/15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /script.php' );`, this will create the file, and already put in the line you need. Then `exec( 'crontab textfile.txt' );` will use that line and add it as cron job. Afterwards you can even delete `textile.txt`, you don't need it any more.

Comment: Thank you very much for full explanations!

Answer (score 2):

`10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /www/virtual/username/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1`
There are two main parts:

The first part is "10 * * * *". This is where we schedule the timer.
The rest of the line is the command as it would run from the command line.
The command itself in this example has three parts:

"/usr/bin/php". PHP scripts usually are not executable by themselves. Therefore we need to run it through the PHP parser.
"/www/virtual/username/cron.php". This is just the path to the script.
"> /dev/null 2>&1". This part is handling the output of the script. More on this later.

Please read this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, I should run this command: `crontab -e` and then run this in console:`15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/my/file.php > /dev/null 2>&1` and then run this: `crontab -l` . Is that right? And script in my/file.php will run every 15 minutes?